# Why does Euler's Number appear in so many equations?

Tags: theoretical-chemistry

Is there an intuitive explanation for $e$ in those randomly chosen equations from my theoretical chemistry book:

$$\Phi(x,t)=(2\pi \hbar)^{-1/2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty C(p){\color{red}e}^{i(px-E(p)t)/\hbar} \, \mathrm{d}p$$
$$\psi(x,t) = \phi(x){\color{red}e}^{-iEt/\hbar}$$
$$u_{ij}\equiv u_{ij|z}=(\overline{e}/2)|\mathcal E|\int \Phi_i^\star \cdot z \cdot {\color{red}e}^{ikx}\cdot \Phi_j \, \mathrm{d}V$$

I am aware that Euler's number is the base of an exponential function whose rate of growth is always proportionate to its present value, but it always bothers me that I can't really tell how it finds its way into such equations.

Comment: What makes you think it is more suited for the chemistry SE site and not the mathematical one?

Comment: @Poutnik Since I am concerned here with comtextual application, I think that one knows here more intuitive understanding in the chemical context.

Comment: Chemists seldom care about the Euler number, they have rather  applied approach to exp and ln functions.

Comment: @Poutnik what exactly do you mean with applied approach? I mean don't you have to understand something to apply it in new situations, I mean I somehow need to have a understanding to let Euler's number emerge in those equations.

Comment: Well, the Euler number is in none of those equations explicitly. And for using of the respective functions, you need not to know it either.

Comment: @Poutnik Hmm ok I see, maybe I just still have a problem with thinking more functionally when learning chemistry instead of trying to analyze every part.

Comment: Hello! This is a question that exceeds chemistry and science. However, you partly answered it. $\exp(x)$ is a particular solution to the differential equation $\mathrm{d}y/\mathrm{d}x = y$, so Euler's number appears. The second equation of your image is when you apply separation of variables to the time-dependent Schrodinger's equation (a PDE). The differential equation with respect to time, has the mentiond form.

Comment: Thus, from an epistemological point of view, the question may be formulated: if you consider that reality $=$ our conceptualization, why so many chemical and physical processes follow this simple differential equation? Other examples are first-order irreversible kinetics, radioactive decay, and the list goes on...

Comment: Further e is closely related to sin and cos, and hence periodic functions; before you know it you're into crystallography and anything that requires a Fourier transform, I.e. huge areas of spectroscopy

Comment: A better on-topic title of the question would be: "What is the use of Euler number in chemistry?"

Answer (score 1):

Euler's number $e$ as such is less prominent than the exponential function $f(x)=\exp(x)$. It is this function, not $e$, that appears widely. For instance, the exponential function appears ubiquitously in assessing the asymptotic growth or decay of functions or populations.

In the real domain we certainly have $\exp(x)=e^x$, which is a consequence of the familar limit for $e$ combined with the algebraic properties of the exponential function. But that equality does not carry over into complex analysis. The function $\exp(z)$ is defined as a single-valued Taylor series that converges for all $z$, or equivalently as the unique solution to $df/dz=f, f(0)=1$; whereas $e^z$ is a branched function just like $a^z$ for other constants $a$. Mathematicians who deal with complex variables are well aware of the dustinction between the exponential function and $e$.